# Proper use of capture groups in SED command

Tags: bash, sed

I need to convert a string "1,234" =to=> 1234.
this string is just a part of a bigger line. There are thousands of such lines in the file.

I have written a sed command which is not working as I expect it to.

```
echo \"1,234\" | sed 's/\("\)\([0-9]+\)\(,\)\([0-9]+\)\("\)/\2\4/g'
```

As far as I understand, in this code,

- \1 is "
- \2 is the digits before comma
- \3 is ,
- \4 is the digits after comma

I expect this command to output 1234 which should be \2\4. But it just yields back "1,234". So I think it is not being parsed properly. Some help would be appreciated.

Comment: you need to escape the `+` too

Comment: Use -r to allow such things as ( and + without escaping.

Comment: You don't need to match `"`. Just match digits before and after comma.

Comment: @Sundeep It worked, thanks! :D You can put that as an answer. Why didn't I think of that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you use [POSIX Extended Regular Expressions](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap09.html) (ERE), where you don't have to escape parentheses and the repetition operator. To enable ERE in `sed`, you can use the `-E` switch (or `-r` in GNU `sed`). Your expression will then look like this:

```
$ echo '"1,234"' | sed -E 's/"([0-9]+),([0-9]+)"/\1\2/g'
1234
```

For completeness, your original BRE expression will function properly if you escape the `+`:

```
echo \"1,234\" | sed 's/\("\)\([0-9]\+\)\(,\)\([0-9]\+\)\("\)/\2\4/g'
1234
```

Comment: `-E` does the same as `-r` but works on more versions of sed.

Comment: You're right, thanks. GNU `sed` prefers `-r`, that's why I default to `-r` (it doesn't even mention `-E` in the man pages, actually).

Comment: [Historically this was a GNU extension, but the -E extension has since been added to the POSIX standard (http://austingroupbugs.net/view.php?id=528), so use -E for portability.](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html).

Comment: Ok, the online docs mention the `-E` and the history around it. Thanks @Tom.

Comment: `sed 's/\([0-9]\),\([0-9]\)/\1\2/g;'` should be sufficient.

Comment: @SLePort, it would be sufficient if the OP is not trying to also strip the quotation marks around the number.

Answer (score 0):

Your second and fourth groups contain `[0-9]+`, which matches any digit followed by a plus sign.

It looks like you meant `[0-9]\+`, to match one or more digits.

---

In passing: there's no need to group the parts you'll not be using (`\1`, `\3` and `\5`).  You can simplify to:

```
echo \"1,234\" | sed 's/"\([0-9]\+\),\([0-9]\+\)"/\1\2/g'
```

If you're finding all those `\` hard to handled, you could use Extendend Regular Expression syntax, with the `-E` flag:

```
echo \"1,234\" | sed -E 's/"([0-9]+),([0-9]+)"/\1\2/g'
```